# Check what service is running on a specific tcp/udp port

Tags: command-line, tcp, udp, port

I'm looking for a command-line utility that allows me to check what service (eg: http/ftp/ssh) is running on a specific port of a remote machine.

An example of how I imagine a program like this would operate:

```
kess@KG-PC:~$ portcheck google.com:80
Port 80 of google.com is running a(n) "http" server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do such recognition is by establish connection to this port and grab the banner. Banner (usually) can tell you if this is for example Apache httpd, openssh and so on. The list of banners can be quite big. Also you can try some commands like `GET / HTTP/1` to check if the service answer to them. For plain text command `telnet` can be enough. For encrypted (SSL/TLS) you may need to use `openssl s_client`.

AFAIK `nmap` can do such things so you can download the source and check how is done there.

If you want to use just a tool you can test:

```
nmap -A google.com -p 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ss` with the `-p` option along with a filter to show what process is using a specific port.

Filter by destination port:

```
ss -p dst = :<port>
```

Filter by source port:

```
ss -p src = :<port>
```

Root privileges may be required to obtain processes.

If you do not have access to the remote machine, then you can perform a port scan with `nmap`. This will list open ports and commonly used services associated with the ports but there is no guarantee the service is the one actually used on the machine as ports can be arbitrarily changed.

A basic scan with a specific port range:

```
nmap -p <first-port>-<last-port> <host>
```

Comment: As I understand your solution checks source and destionation ports on my machine, but I want to check a port on a remote machine

Comment: I edited my question to further clarify my requirement.